# How to deal with objects that sometimes have a field missing in lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-object

I have a custom object that has fields that sometimes has data and sometimes doesn't.  I'm trying to loop through those fields in my component, but having big problems because the field doesn't show up on the objects where it is blank.

IE Object 1 has field, object 2 doesn't all are in a array returned to component.

So I figure maybe I can just test to see if the field is missing and add in something in javascript, but it's not even letting me do that.  For example if field's name is Tier__c,  and object variable name is prod

I've tried

```
try { if (prod.Tier__C) {} catch (e) { prod.Tier__c = '' }

if ($A.util.isEmpty(prod.Tier__C)

if (prod.hasOwnProperty(Tier__C)
```

But in all cases I get the error "Error during init [Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined]"

any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: It's `__c`, not `__C`. JavaScript is case sensitive. Make sure that you're respecting case sensitivity. And none of those constructs should ordinarily be necessary. I have a feeling you've misidentified the cause of the issue.

Comment: Maybe, but I put "if (prod.Tier__c == NULL) {prod.Tier__c = 'Tier 1';} "  in my apex class and the error went away....

Comment: You were right, I was wrong, I found my error, I was missing a "V" somewhere